# Change the maximum size of a file upload - symfony

Tags: file-upload, symfony-1.4

Can I change the maximum size from a file that is being upload (using the sfValidatorFile and the sfWidgetFormInputFile) from 2MB to a bit more? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the validator option (in bytes)

> max_size

Of course it can't exceed upload_max_filesize in php.ini

Comment: can I change the upload_max_field from php.ini?

Comment: You can if you have a virtual or dedicated production server. No change is allowed by providers for hosting service that is based on shared server.

Comment: I've to change upload_max_filesize and post_max_size too. Now it works... thank you